# How to set some values of tensor as zero value in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to sparse the convolution kernels，so I need to set some values in  the kernels as zero value in the training process. Are there some apis in the tensorflow  to help me realize my idea, to set some values in the tensor as zero?

Comment: for example, how to find the value in the tensor whose value is lower than 0.0001, then set the value as 0?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use [tf.boolean_mask](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask)`(original_tensor, mask)` to keep only the values that you want (you'll remove the other ones instead of setting them to 0).

To keep the initial shape and just have zeros in some places, you can just do something like that:

```
new_tensor = tf.multiply(original_tensor, tf.cast(mask, original_tensor.type()))
```

For your example, you could build the mask with sthg like:

```
mask = tf.less(original_tensor, 0.0001 * tf.ones_like(original_tensor))
```

Comment: Thanks, I've looked for this. Now I'm applying this to image inputs to threshold certain pixel values.
`threshold_mask = tf.greater(image_op, 60)`
`image_op = image_op * tf.cast(threshold_mask, dtype=tf.uint8)`

Comment: The link is broken. The current link is: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask

Answer (score 4):

**tf.relu_layer()** is what you're looking for, which is itself calling **tf.nn.relu()** with

> tensor * weight + bias

So you could just call

```
tf.nn.relu_layer(tensor, 1.0, -your_threshold)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/relu_layer