# TF: mask random rectangle in image.

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to mask a image with a 10x10 rectangle which I position randomly in the image. Eg. set that values of the [batch, height, width, col_channels] to zero.

In numpy I would do [:, random_x:random_x+10, random_y:random_y+10, :] = 0.

Is there a possibility doing this in tensor-flow in a elegant way?

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43954298/how-to-set-some-values-of-tensor-as-zero-value-in-tensorflow

Comment: @Lescurel yes I read that one but masking values above a threshold is quite straight forward but  masking a specific area which is randomized is not (as least I havent found a easy solution).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how elegant it is, but my solution uses tensorflow operations instead of numpy ops. Therefore, it can provide different random values while running inside a `@tf.function`:

randomize the rectangle:

```
x1, y1 = tf.random.uniform([2], maxval=255)
```

create the mask:

```
mask = tf.concat([
    tf.zeros([img_size, y1]),
    tf.concat([tf.zeros([x1, y2-y1]), tf.ones([x2-x1, y2-y1]), tf.zeros([img_size - x2, y2-y1])], axis=0),
    tf.zeros([img_size, img_size - y2])
  ], axis=1)
mask = tf.stack([mask] * channels, axis=2)
```

apply the mask:

```
tf.boolean_mask(img, mask)
```

Comment: For last line, alternatively, you can just img*mask, just in case tf.boolean_mask didn't give what you want.